# Why do my buttons stay pressed?

Tags: android, graphics, button, state

In my activity I respond to an onClick() by replacing the current view with a new one (setContentView()). For some reason when I do this and then go back to the original view later the button I originally pressed still looks like it is pressed.

If you 'refresh' it somehow (e.g. scroll over it with the trackball) then it reverts to the unpressed state. It's as if the button doesn't get the 'touch-up' event.

The weird thing is: This only happens on my T-Mobile Pulse (android 1.5). It doesn't happen on the emulator.

I've tried calling invalidate()/postInvalidate() on the view when I show it but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your "touch-up" event will go to your new content view.

You can either:

- Not call `setContentView()` at all in `onClick()`, using other means of achieving your UI aims (multiple activities, `ViewFlipper`, etc.).
- Not call `setContentView()` *immediately* in `onClick()`, but instead `post()` a `Runnable` that will call `setContentView()`. That should put the content view replacement in the event queue after the "touch-up" event.

Personally, I am not a big fan of activities constantly calling `setContentView()`, as I worry about memory leaks and overly-plump activities making state and memory management more difficult. For example, let's say you call `setContentView()` for your original layout (A), then call `setContentView()` for your new layout (B), then the user rotates the screen. Android's default `onSaveInstanceState()` will help you with B -- hanging onto `EditText` contents and the like -- but for A, you're on your own.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about ViewFlipper (or ViewSwitcher!) Looks like exactly what I want. Example here for future readers: http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/android_dont_overlook_viewswitcher/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `onClick()` executes before the button's View gets set back to its unclicked state and since you remove the view before that happens, it maintains its clicked state. You could try something like requesting focus with another item during the `onClick()`. However, calling a `setContentView()` repeatedly on a screen sounds a little strange. Are you sure you shouldn't be using another `Activity`? That would fix your button state issue.